# Is Gojou-sensei blind?

Tags: jujutsu-kaisen

So far, all of the time's we've seen Gojo-sensei, his eye's have been covered by some patch/bandage/blindfold. Is it cause he is blind and hence wants to conceal some terrible injury he probably got from a battle? And if so how come he can still fight perfectly.

If not why does he prefer to cover his eyes, even while in battle. Also, how can he still move around perfectly with the blindfold, it most definitely is not completely transparent.

Answer (score 2):

[Satoru Gojo](https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Satoru_Gojo) is always seen wearing his signature black blindfold and otherwise a pair of dark eyeglasses not because he is blind but because it is *a part of who he is*; it is distinctive and has become one of his signature character traits.

[image]

The writers wished to symbolize the importance of his eyes, which *often see more than they see less*. In addition, this also serves as a barrier and a way in which Gojo manages to keep himself distanced from others while teaching.

[image]

Proof he does see is provide during chapter 0-1 the [Cursed Child Arc](https://jujutsu-kaisen.fandom.com/wiki/Chapter_0-1) when he confronts Getou, *we see his glasses practically fall off of him in this scene because it’s impossible for him to remain blind*. Therefore, his eyeglasses serve as means of defence for retaining his emotions and enable him to find balance with himself.

Comment: ah so thats the prequel volume to the current arc in the anime

Comment: I dont get the "eyes that see more than they see less" point tho

Comment: His eyes often see more due to his years of experience in combat, he is able to read others to the point that he no longer sees them as individual people. This is a problem given his position is a pedestal in the anime, where he must be empathetic towards his pupils. Gojo perceives the infinity instead and how every single person on earth has a rich internal world filled with their own congitions and biases.